# Include base64 code of image in csv file using Nifi

Tags: base64, apache-nifi

I have json array response from InvokeHTTP. I am using the below Flow to convert some json info to csv. One of the json info is id which is used to get image and then convert it to base64. I need to add this base64 code to my csv. I don't understand how to save it in an attribute so that it can be put in AttributeToCsv. [image: Nifi Flowfile diagram to convert json response to csv]

Also, I was reading here https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Nifi-attribute-containing-large-text-value/td-p/190513
that it is not recommended to store large values in attributes due to memory concern. What would be an optimal approach in this scenario.

Json response during first call:

```
[ {
  "fileNumber" : "1",
   "uuid" : "abc",
  "attachedFiles" : [ {
    "id" : "bkjdbkjdsf",
    "name" : "image1.png",
  }, {
    "id" : "xzcv",
    "name" : "image2.png",
  } ],
  "date":null
  },
  { "fileNumber" : "2",
   "uuid" : "def",
  "attachedFiles" : [],
  "date":null
  }]
```

Final Csv (after merge or expected output):

```
Id,File Name, File Data(base64 code)
bkjdbkjdsf,image1.png, iVBORw0KGgo...ji
xzcv,image1.png,ZEStWRGau..74
```

My approach (will change as per suggestions):
After splitting Json response, I use EvaluateJsonPath to get "attachedFiles".
I find length of array "attachedFiles" and then decide if need to split further if 2 or more files are there. If 0 then do nothing. In second EvaluateJsonPath I add properties Id,File Name and set the values from json using `$.id` etc.. I use the Id to invoke other URL which I encode to Base64.

Current output - csv file which needs to be updated with third column File Data(base64 code) and it's value:

```
Id,File Name
bkjdbkjdsf,image1.png
xzcv,image1.png
```

Comment: You can save an image on some storage and keep in csv just path to the image. This way your nifi will work in more efficient way.

Comment: Firstly, to clear up some terminology. The screenshot you shared is a Flow, NOT a FlowFile. A FlowFile is the object/data/messsage that is passed between Processors, and a FlowFile can have Attributes and Content. Typically, a FlowFile's Attributes are in memory, while it's Content is on disk. Thus, typically you should only be using Attributes for metadata or small pieces of frequently accessed data (where going to disk is inefficient). It looks to me like you are using Attributes too much for data, especially for the Base64 encoded image which should really only ever be in FlowFile Content.

Comment: You are using a lot of EvaluteJsonPath and SplitJsons, which is usually a bit of an anti-pattern. Instead, you should look at using Records and enriching each record with a LookupRecord to get the image and then insert the Base64 into each record. I wrote a post about a similar flow, see if it gives you some ideas https://alasdairb.com/2021/05/16/enriching-records-with-lookuprecord-rest-apis-in-nifi/

Comment: @Pan, in AttributesToCsv - you want to create one line(row) of csv - right? could you show an example of flowfile you are expecting before merge?

Comment: @Sdairs, I went through the link and came to know about this awesome processor LookupRecord. It would solve all the problem. Basically first part is same as CovertRecord which I use a lot.  Second part, where we need to add a Record Reader service, the Reader that is used to understand the results of the API call. In my case it will return an image which needs to be converted to Base64. I can't find anything to read image

Comment: I haven't tested this - but a potential option could be to use a ScriptedReader as the Record Reader for the Lookup result, which would let you take in the Image result and then use Python or Groovy to return the Base64 string as the Record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as a variant use ExecuteGroovyScript:

```js
def ff=session.get()
if(!ff)return

ff.write{sin, sout->
    sout.withWriter('UTF-8'){w->
        //write attribute values for names 'Id' and 'filename' delimited with coma
        w << ff.attributes.with{a->[a.'Id', a.'filaname']}.join(',')
        w << ',' //wtite coma
        
        //sin.withReader('UTF-8'){r-> w << r} //write current content of the file after last coma
        w << sin.bytes.encodeBase64()
        w << '\n'
    }
}
REL_SUCCESS << ff
```

---

**UPD:** i put `sin.bytes.encodeBase64()` instead of copying flowfile content. this one creates one-line base64 string for input file. if you are using this option - you should remove Base64EncodeContent to prevent double base64 encoding.

Comment: I have implement ExecuteGroovyScript after Base64Encode. It outputs  bkjdbkjdsf,image1.png, iVBORw0KGgo...ji  as needed. I have deleted AttributeToCsv as I think it is no longer required.  But somehow it is failing at MergeRecord. I am getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Index for header 'image1' is 1 but CSVRecord only has 1 values!   Is my approach correct?   ExecuteGroovyScript joins with RouteOnAttribute and this joins to MergeRecord.

Comment: If I comment the groovy script where base64 code is appended then this error at MergeRecord is gone. base64 has  "/" maybe  causing the issue

Comment: any improvements or suggestions for above @daggett

Comment: truthfully i don't think the whole approach is good. imageB64 is larger then one image. if you have large images - the cvs could go very heavy... however i don't remember if base64encode is producing one-lined base64 string. if not  - i've updated the response...

Comment: Thanks, encodeBase64() in script actually put the base64 code in a line, so no error . But, still following MergeRecord after that is not merging the content.     
Merge Strategy: Defragment
Correlation Attribute Name :No value set                                                              
Attribute Strategy : Keep All Unique Attributes
Minimum Number of Records : 2000
Maximum Number of Records:10000
Minimum Bin Size:500 B
Maximum Bin Size : No value set                                                                                  Max Bin Age : 5 min
Maximum Number of Bins : 5

Comment: One more change I did was to use MergeContent instead of MergeRecord @daggett